# Number of collinear subsets in a set

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math

Call a set of points $(x,y)$ *good* if all the points in the set are collinear (i.e. they all lie on a line).Let S be the set of points $(x,y)$ such that $0\leq x,y \leq n$ ( $ x,y $ are restricted to be integers)

For finding the number of such subsets I have tried many approaches- brute force, finding slopes. But they dont work because of large input. Is there anything I am missing or is there any other approach that reduces the time complexity?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ restricted to integers? Are you counting singletons? And the empty set?

Comment: Yes $x$ and $y$ are integers. And yes I am counting singletons and empty subsets.

Comment: "contest-math"? Which contest?

Comment: Ok it's not a contest question

Comment: How large is this “large input”?

Comment: N can be as large as 10^11

Comment: I did [some rather brute-force computation](http://ideone.com/T1HlZK) to obtain some initial elements, but unfortunately the sequence I found, `1,2,11,54,191,554,1375,3206,6971,14850,31055,64766`, isn't listed on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/). I guess one could add that sequence to the database once we know more about it. Note that your count appears to grow faster than $2^n$, so for $n=10^{11}$ you're asking for a number with more than $3\times10^{10}$ digits! Unless I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I think you are missing some sets because the number of such sets for $ n=4$ is $253$ (including singleton sets). Sorry, I failed to mention, the question asks for the ans modulo 1000000007

Comment: Please [write @username](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) when replying to a person who is not owner of the post you comment on. As to that modulo requirement, you probably should edit your question to include that. And give a link to the official problem statement as well, if possible. The $n=4$ case in your formulation (i.e. with $n$ *inclusive*) corresponds to the `554` answer in my list, so it looks more like I'm counting things twice.

Comment: For $n=4$, you have $5$ coordinates satisfying $0\le x\le 4$, so you have $5\times5=25$ points, and $\binom52=300$ two-element sets. So for $n=4$ a count of 253 must be wrong. For $n=3$ you have $4\times4=16$ points. This gives $1$ empty set, $16$ singletons, $\binom42=120$ pairs, 44 triplets (16 for horizontal and vertical, 6 for slopes $\pm1$) and 10 quadruplets (4 hor/vert., 1 per slope $\pm1$), together $1+16+120+44+10=191$ as indicated. Looks like either I'm misunderstanding the problem or there is a mistake in its statement or your expected answer for the $n=4$ case.

Comment: @MvG Sorry, your answer is correct. 253 is the answer excluding 2 element sets and null set. The problem - http://projecteuler.net/problem=415. Can you explain what did you do in your brute force computation, I can't understand your code.

Comment: There is [a tag for project euler](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/project-euler/info). Its tag wiki provides [two](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1090/35416) [links](http://forum.projecteuler.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2707) you should probably read. Bottom line: they don't want their questions answered anywhere else. But as you didn't copy that question, but are asking a different question, it might be OK although you probably should add the (problem-euler) tag. Although since that question both asks for a different number and uses a different modulus, the relation is unclear to me.